# Why the function apply's args can only space the later site?

Tags: python, dataframe, function, arguments, apply

Question1

I'm trying to let a dataframe columns add the same number.

Trying use apply to make columns add a number.

First define a function call 'apply_age'

```
def apply_age(x,bias):
    return x+bias

data["age"] = data["age"].apply(apply_age,args=(50,))
#it can work
```

but

```
def apply_age(x,bias):
    return x+bias

data["age"] = data["age"].apply(apply_age,args=(,50))
#it can't work,and show SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Question2

Why type 2 number in each site will get error ?

Which is 'TypeError: apply_age() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given
def apply_age(x,bias)'

```
data["age"] = data["age"].apply(apply_age,args=(50,2))
```

Comment: [Code samples](/help/mcve) should be *minimal*, complete and representative. For the first question, `(,50)` is all that's needed for a code sample. Please look over the [help], especially the "[ask]" article, and "[How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/90527)".

Answer (score 0):

Can you just use a lambda function instead?

```
bias = 50
df['age'] = df['age'].apply(lambda x: x+bias)
```

Comment: Txs,but I wanna know what the reason the function use and learn the relation about apply and arg.

Comment: the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) have an example that covers this